# Should [energy] be renamed to [energy-impact] or be a synonym of [power-management]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[energy-saving](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-saving) is already a synonym of [power-management](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management), but [energy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) is separate. It is used on a variety of questions, mostly in unison with [power-management](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management) for general energy questions, or when talking about the Energy Impact.

Is [energy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) supposed to be referring to the Energy Impact? The tag has no wiki or excerpt. If so, could the tag be renamed to [energy-impact](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-impact) to make that clear? If not, could it be a synonym of [power-management](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management)?